# Edit button is disabled in a team provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode-organizer

I added new device UDID on my apple account . Then i need to select this device in my provisioning profile team but edit button is disabled. Some blogs are saying go to Xcode organiser and press refresh button but window has been updated so there are no refresh button in organiser.
And for total device, it is showing 43 total in team provisioning profile screen.

Please help me.